# Core Data Fetched Properties

Tags: ios, core-data, persistent-storage

Though I have been using Core Data for a while now and in a number of apps, I have never yet used Fetched Properties.

In my current project I have an entity with relationships in the Default store, this same entity is also in the Second store.
But in the Second store I want to have some of the relationships changed to Fetched Properties.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace relationships with fetched properties, but it won't be the same entity anymore. Migrating to a new model using fetched properties is possible, but unless you're using different models for different store files you'll need to make the change in both places. If you want the same model for both, you might consider adding a fetched property while keeping the relationship in place.